# Best practice for angular controllers in coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

What is the best practice in creating angular controllers using coffee script classes? I've been googling for a while, but haven't found a really nice solution so far.

According to [this article](http://alxhill.com/blog/articles/angular-coffeescript/) author suggest the following approach:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller 'SomeCtrl',
  class SomeCtrl
    someModels: -> ...
```

However, it is not clarified how to make any injections to such a controller. Since coffee is automatically moving all methods to constructor's prototype I will not be able to access injected services within those methods.

So far the only way to get around this is:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller 'SomeCtrl',
  class SomeCtrl
    @$inject: ['SomeService']
    constructor: (someService) -> 
      @load = ->
        # access to someService
```

Obviously this is quite ugly, not to mention memory-inefficient.

So the question is, what is the best way to define angular controller using Coffee goodies?

EDIT:

There is another option to explicitly use an injector:

```
app = angular.module('myApp')
injector = angular.injector([app.name])

injector.invoke ['SomeService', (SomeService) -> 
  app.controller 'SomeCtrl',
    class SomeCtrl
      foo: 'bar'
      func: ->
        # Prototype function with access to SomeService without exposing it in API.
]
```

This however makes code order dependent and is ugly as hell.

What I would be looking for ideally is some sort of way to define a controller as a factory - instead of passing constructor function I would like to pass a function which is to return a constructor. Is anything like this possible?

Comment: Have you considered `constructor: (@someService) ->` and then using `@someService` in other methods?

Comment: @Oleg - It is an idea, however it feels a little bit wrong with services being exposed in controller API. Still better then defining all the functions in the constructor.

Comment: Or you can simply use a function. You're not forced to use a class.

Comment: @Oleg - True, but there are no named functions in Coffee. Even with a function though I need to define all the methods directly on the new object, which seems memory inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

First define the class, adding required services in the constructor...

```
class SomeCtrl
  constructor: (someService)-> alert someService 9
```

Next, attach as controller to app...

```
angular.module('myApp').controller 'SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl
```

### Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zrv8vx8/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

... and ...

```
angular.module 'myApp', []
angular.module('myApp').factory 'someService', ->
  (x)-> x * x;

class SomeCtrl
  constructor: (someService)-> alert someService 9
  someModels: ->

angular.module('myApp').controller 'SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My main concern is however how to access injected services within other instance functions than constructor. For services I can create the whole class within a function returning the class, so all the elements has an access to all injected services, however controller requires direct constructor without wrapping clojure. This doesn't really seem to be very coffee related problem.

Comment: @BroiSatse, did you figure out how to go about doing this? Searching for a similar solution.